# Unit test failure in C# Prime Factors Kata

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, prime-factoring

Longtime programmer, new to C#. Just started on the Prime Factors Kata using VS2012 and the built-in test framework. On the first test, the expected and actual match, yet it's flagged as a failure. Can anyone explain why, and more importantly what the work-around is?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace PrimeFactorsKata
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private static List<int> ExpectedList()
        {
            return new List<int>();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestOne()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedList(), PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1));
        }
    }

    class PrimeFactorGenerator
    {
        public static List<int> Generate(int n)
        {
            return new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]>. 
Actual:<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]>. 

   at PrimeFactorsTest.UnitTest1.TestOne() in UnitTest1.cs: line 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other's have mentioned you are comparing the references of each list, which are different.  To compare the contents you can use [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx)

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestOne()
{
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ExpectedList(), PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1));
}
```

You can also check out other methods on [`CollectionAssert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) like [`AreEquivalent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243779.aspx)

There are also overrides for each that allow you to pass an `IComparer` to determine how you want to compare the items in the collections.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to compare two different object references.

```
Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedList(), PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1));
```

This is calling `ExpectedList()` then it is calling `PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1)`. Each one of the calls is creating and returning a reference to a **new** object (because of the `new` keyword you have). The `Assert.AreEqual()` is then comparing the references which obviously are not the same.

It is important to understand the difference between the reference and the object content. The reference is a pointer to the object value (content).

What you need to do is to loop through the two lists and compare the content (assuming that you inserted some data in them, in your sample they are empty but this code will still work):

```
var l1 = ExpectedList();
var l2 = PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1);

Assert.AreEqual(l1.Count, l2.Count);

if (l1.Count > 0) //Make sure you have data
    for (int i = 0, i < l1.Count, i++)
        Assert.AreEqual(l1[i], l2[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Default equality for reference types in C# is instance equality - your assertion fails because the two parameters aren't the same instance of `List<T>`. There's no out of the box `Assert` for sequence equality in MSTest, but you can use something like [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `Assert.IsTrue` to the same effect, e.g.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestOne()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(ExpectedList().SequenceEqual(PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1));
}
```

Edit:

Apparently there *are* collection assertions in MSTest (thanks to @juharr), which would simplify your test to

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestOne()
{
    CollectionAsssert.AreEquivalent(ExpectedList(), PrimeFactorGenerator.Generate(1));
}
```

Comment: Check out [`CollectionAssert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx)